# Placing a button inside a rendered partial that hides the partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, render, partial

```
<%= render :partial => "list" %>
```

Inside this partial there is only one div. I would like to have a button in the top right corner of the div to close the div. I would like the button to "not render" the partial and just display the rest of the index.html.

How should I code the button in rails? It will be a small png. Thanks

Comment: What version of Rails are you using? The actual implementation of how you do this changes from version to version if you take advantage of new features

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your layout

```
<html>
<head>
<%= javascript_include_tag "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js", "home.js" %>    
</head>
```

home.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#close-it').live('click', function() {
$('#list').hide();
});

});
```

_list.html.erb

```
<div id="list">

<%= image_tag("button.png", :id => "close-it") %>

</div>
```